# Defer read states for side effects in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

On compose screen I have screen level state from ViewModel:

```kotlin
val actionResult: State<Result> = remember { viewModel.actionResult }
```

Also, i need to listen changes of this state for result and start something in LaunchedEffect (show snackbar).

What is best practic for read actionResult.value and avoid recomposition of all screen?
Are there any drawbacks in my solution (described below)?

---

Simpliest code with all screen recomposition when actionResult.value is requested:

```kotlin
Screen {
    val viewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()
    val actionResult: State<Result?> = remember { viewModel.actionResult }
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    LaunchedEffect(actionResult.value) {
        val result = actionResult.value
        result ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        val snackbarResult = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = "Action is Done!")
        viewModel.clearActionResult()
    }

    /* other composables */
}
```

Passing this parameter to child composables (e.g. Scaffold with snackbar) also is not elegance because of required large count of unclear parameters.

My solution is to create separate @Composable function EventHandler and read changes inside.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EventHandler(isEvent: () -> Boolean, onEvent: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (isEvent()) onEvent()
}

Screen {
    val viewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()
    val actionResult: State<Result?> = remember { viewModel.actionResult }
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    EventHandler(isEvent = { actionResult.value != null }) {
        scope.launch @coroutineScope{
            val result = actionResult.value
            result ?: return@coroutineScope
            val snackbarResult = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = "Action is Done!")
            viewModel.clearActionResult()
        }
    }

    /* other composables */
}
```

Comment: you can use ```SharedFlow``` for showing the Toast, SnackBar Or any one-time events. which is the best practice in ```Jetpack Compose```

Comment: @ChiragThummar, you suggest using SharedFlow emmiting result and collect it in remembered coroutine scope on Screen?

Comment: You can catch the value in ```LaunchedEffect```

Comment: @ChiragThummar, SharedFlow is cleanest solution but is not working when result state is changes with navigation to second screen. Result is emmiting earlier than happening returning to the first screen. So i've using the similar function as mentioned EventHandler but more specific for the concrete actions with second screen result. The function is read performed action state and second screen result value (from first screen constructor).